# Xamarin C# Android 7.0 on Moto G5 Plus phone, dialog fragment window transparent background rendering error issue

Tags: android, xamarin, android-dialogfragment, android-7.0-nougat

I have been trying to solve this issue for 2 days now, with no luck.

I have a DialogFragment which I would like to have a transparent window background.

The way I did it is overriding the DialogFragment class' `OnResume` like below.

```
public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of what it is doing:

[image: Dialog Fragment with transparent window]
NOTE:

1. I have tried using a PNG transparent background too, with no luck `Dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawableResource(Resource.Drawable.transparent);`
2. This issue only happens on Android 7.0 devices. The other phone and tablet running Android 6++ are rendering the tranparency just fine

Comment: Does this issue happens on all android version 7.0+ device? Or just in Moto G5 Plus phone?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one Android 7.0 device, however all Android devices (phones and tablets) with Android 5 and 6 are rendering the Dialog Fragment Window's transparent background just fine.

Comment: I test on my M 6 with Android 7.0, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input York, i think i will create a fresh new project and test this again.

Comment: I have created a fresh project and ran it on the same phone (Moto G5 Plus) and the DialogFragment window transparency works!! I wonder if Android.Support.AppCompat's Theme.Light applied on my real project is the culprit here! I will test further and update you guys ASAP